# jquery .get() or .ajax() procceded successfully, but with empty data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I get some html data via ajax with jquery .get() or tried .ajax() too on localhost

in firebug console I see the ajax request like:
GET http://localhost/ci4/public_html/beta/kosik/pridat/29/1 200OK 143ms BUT in red color

in header tab - response headers is info about Content-Length   233
but in response tab is no data

I logged server response and it is not null:
INFO  - 2012-01-21 10:13:33 --> info#Výrobok **magnetka " škuľavá** bol vložený do košíka, celkovo máte v košíku položky v počte **2**  v celkovej cene 29.70 €.

```
function add_item_to_cart(id_item) {
    cnt = $("#item-count-select").val();
    var baseurl = $("#baseurl").val();
    var service_url = baseurl+'kosik/pridat/'+id_item+'/'+cnt;
    $("#item-header").append('<div id="spinner-div" style="padding-top: 0px;"><img id="spinner"  style=" margin-left: 18px;" src="'+baseurl+'imgd/item-flower-anim.gif"/></div>');
        /*
    $.get(service_url, function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          alert(data);
      if (data.substr(0,4) == 'warn') {
          $("#flash-warning-div").html(data.substr(8));
          $("#flash-warning-div").slideDown('fast');
      } else if (data.substr(0,4) == 'info'){
          $("#flash-info-div").html(data.substr(5));
          $("#cart-header-sum").html($("#cart-total").html());
          $("#flash-info-div").slideDown('fast');
      } else {
          $("#flash-warning-div").html('Neznáma chyba pri vkladaní do košíka');
          $("#flash-warning-div").slideDown('fast');
      }
      $("#spinner-div").remove();
    });*/
        $.ajax({
            url: service_url,
            success: function (data) {
                if (console && console.log){
                    console.log( 'Sample of data:', data.slice(0,100) );
                }
            },
            dataType: 'html'
        });


}
```

Comment: what happens if you access the url directly?

Comment: Content Encoding 
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.
        
Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

strange, few days ago it worked fine

Comment: other ajaxs requests work pretty fine on site

Comment: OK got it, codeigniter config parameter $config['compress_output'] = TRUE; caused that,